# ¿Cómo puedo poner un salto de línea en un return, en el lenguaje JS?

Tags: javascript

Estoy utilizando Visual Studio Code con 3 archivos: **un html, un css y un JavaScript**. Estuve intentando que la información que se imprima en pantalla se vea agradable a la vista a la hora de terminar los cálculos, ya intenté con `\n` y no me ha funcionado, también intenté usar `document.write(function)` y `console.log(function)` y tampoco me han funcionado.

**Este es mi código:**

```
function calcFlujo (peso){
    const unidad ="Kg";
    let metodo, resultado;
    if (peso <30) {
        metodo = "Hollidar-Segar";
        const volumenDiario = peso * 100;
        const mantenimiento = Math.round(volumenDiario / 24 * 1,5 *10)/ 10 ;
        const mm = peso + (peso/2);
        resultado = `Volumen diario: ${volumenDiario} cc, \n 
                     Mantenimiento: ${mantenimiento}cc/hr, \n
                     m+m/2: ${mm}`;  // Mi problema esta en estas 3 últimas líneas.     
    } 
    else {
        metodo = "Superficie Corporal";
        const sc1500 = peso * 1500;
        const sc2000 = peso * 2000;
        resultado = `SC * 1500: ${sc1500}, SC * 2000: ${sc2000}`;
    }
    return `Para un peso de ${peso} ${unidad}, \n 
            Se utilizo el metodo ${metodo}. \n 
            ${resultado}.`;  // Mi problema esta en estas 3 últimas líneas.
}
```

**Quiero que al imprimirlo se vea algo como:**

*Para un peso de 20 Kg,*

*Se utilizo el metodo Hollidar-Segar.*

*Volumen diario: 2000 cc,*

*Mantenimiento: 8.3 cc/hr,*

*m+m/2: 2010. cc/hr*

*m+m/2 NaN cc/hr*

Comment: Saludos. Prueba lo siguiente: Si la salida es digamos en un `alert` en lugar de `\n` coloca `\\n`; si la salida será como contenido html usa `<br />` o cada texto ponlo en un `<p>[Mensaje a mostrarse en una línea]</p>`.

Answer (score 4):

Como estás usando [*plantillas de cadenas*](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), basta nada más con agregar y quitar los espacios y *enters* cuando corresponda. **Ni siquiera es necesario colocar el `\n`**.

Ojo que anteriormente parecía más "ordenado" el código (por los espacios adicionales con que contaba para que aparezca "alineada" la cadena), pero esto hacía justamente que no se imprima tal cadena como se esperaba.

```js
function calcFlujo (peso){
    const unidad ="Kg";
    let metodo, resultado;
    if (peso <30) {
        metodo = "Hollidar-Segar";
        const volumenDiario = peso * 100;
        const mantenimiento = Math.round(volumenDiario / 24 * 1,5 *10)/ 10 ;
        const mm = peso + (peso/2);
        resultado = `Volumen diario: ${volumenDiario} cc,
Mantenimiento: ${mantenimiento}cc/hr,
m+m/2: ${mm}`;  // Mi problema esta en estas 3 últimas líneas.     
    } 
    else {
        metodo = "Superficie Corporal";
        const sc1500 = peso * 1500;
        const sc2000 = peso * 2000;
        resultado = `SC * 1500: ${sc1500}, SC * 2000: ${sc2000}`;
    }
    return `Para un peso de ${peso} ${unidad},
Se utilizo el metodo ${metodo}.
${resultado}.`;  // Mi problema esta en estas 3 últimas líneas.
}

console.log(calcFlujo(10))
```

Con *enters* intercalados (tal como se muestra en la pregunta):

```js
function calcFlujo (peso){
    const unidad ="Kg";
    let metodo, resultado;
    if (peso <30) {
        metodo = "Hollidar-Segar";
        const volumenDiario = peso * 100;
        const mantenimiento = Math.round(volumenDiario / 24 * 1,5 *10)/ 10 ;
        const mm = peso + (peso/2);
        resultado = `Volumen diario: ${volumenDiario} cc,

Mantenimiento: ${mantenimiento}cc/hr,

m+m/2: ${mm}`;  // Mi problema esta en estas 3 últimas líneas.     
    } 
    else {
        metodo = "Superficie Corporal";
        const sc1500 = peso * 1500;
        const sc2000 = peso * 2000;
        resultado = `SC * 1500: ${sc1500}, SC * 2000: ${sc2000}`;
    }
    return `Para un peso de ${peso} ${unidad},

Se utilizo el metodo ${metodo}.

${resultado}.`;  // Mi problema esta en estas 3 últimas líneas.
}

console.log(calcFlujo(10))
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes apoyarte en la etiqueta `<br>` para insertar los saltos de línea.

```js
calcFlujo(20);

function calcFlujo(peso) {
  let mostrar = document.getElementById('mostrar');
  const unidad = "Kg";
  let metodo, resultado;
  if (peso < 30) {
    metodo = "Hollidar-Segar";
    const volumenDiario = peso * 100;
    const mantenimiento = Math.round(volumenDiario / 24 * 1, 5 * 10) / 10;
    const mm = peso + (peso / 2);
    resultado = `Volumen diario: ${volumenDiario} cc,<br>
        Mantenimiento: ${mantenimiento}cc/hr,<br>
        m+m/2: ${mm}`;
  } else {
    metodo = "Superficie Corporal";
    const sc1500 = peso * 1500;
    const sc2000 = peso * 2000;
    resultado = `SC * 1500: ${sc1500}, SC * 2000: ${sc2000}`;
  }
  mostrar.innerHTML += (`Para un peso de ${peso} ${unidad},<br>
    Se utilizo el metodo ${metodo}.<br>
    ${resultado}.`)
}
```

```html
<div id="mostrar"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Veo que los \n no están acompañados de sus correspondientes comillas dobles en vez de las simples...
Yo te aconsejaría lo siguiente:

```
function calcFlujo (peso){
    const unidad ="Kg";
    let metodo, resultado;
    if (peso < 30) {
        metodo = "Hollidar-Segar";
        const volumenDiario = peso * 100;
        const mantenimiento = Math.round(volumenDiario / 24 * 1,5 *10)/ 10 ;
        const mm = peso + (peso/2);
        resultado = 'Volumen diario: ${volumenDiario} cc,' + "\n" + 
                 ' Mantenimiento: ${mantenimiento}cc/hr,' + "\n" +
                 'm+m/2: ${mm}';  // Mi problema esta en estas 3 últimas líneas.     
    }else{
        metodo = "Superficie Corporal";
        const sc1500 = peso * 1500;
        const sc2000 = peso * 2000;
        resultado = 'SC * 1500: ${sc1500}, SC * 2000: ${sc2000}';
    }
    return 'Para un peso de ${peso} ${unidad},' + "\n" +  
        ' Se utilizo el metodo ${metodo}.' + "\n" + 
        ' ${resultado}.';  // Mi problema esta en estas 3 últimas líneas.
}
```